# Is there a way to set variables in a scenario and use them in another scenario in karate framework?

Tags: bdd, karate

I get a value in the response by running one of the scenarios and I would like to use that value in the next scenario. Is there a way to set variables in the context of a feature with karate? I know I can call another feature from within the feaure, but I don't want to move that scenario in another feature and do the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that having scenarios depend on another is considered a bad practice, and I don't recommend it: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

But please refer this section on "hooks": https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

Comment: I have managed to build my scenarios so I avoid the dependency, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @cris how did you achieve this? i need to do the same